# Как в webpack сделать так, что бы после компиляции на выходе я получил НЕ минифицированную версию CSS?

Tags: javascript, css, webpack, postcss

Как отключить минифицированние стилей в webpack?
Такой вот код в webpack.config.js

В итоге компиляции получаю минифицированную версию стилей.

```
module: {
    rules: [{
        test: /\.(sa|sc|c)ss$/,
        use: [
            'style-loader',
            {
                loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader
            },
            {
                loader: "css-loader"
            },
            {
                loader: "postcss-loader"
            },
            {
                loader: "sass-loader"
            }
        ]
    }]
},
```

---

В итоге хочу получить 2 файла: app.css, app.min.css
Код полностью:

```
const path = require('path')
const webpack = require('webpack')
const UglifyJsPlugin = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin')
const OptimizeCssAssetsPlugin = require('optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin')
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin')

module.exports = [{
    entry: {
        "app": "./src/js/app.js",
        "app.min": "./src/js/app.js"
    },
    output: {
      filename: '[name].js',
      library: settings.library,
      path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist/js')
    },
    module: {
        rules: [{
            test: /\.m?js$/,
            exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
            use: {
                loader: 'babel-loader'
            }
        }, {
            test: /\.(sa|sc|c)ss$/,
            use: [
                'style-loader',
                {
                    loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                },
                {
                    loader: "css-loader"
                },
                {
                    loader: "postcss-loader"
                },
                {
                    loader: "sass-loader"
                }
            ]
        }]
    },
    plugins: [
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
            filename: '../css/[name].css'
        }),
        new OptimizeCssAssetsPlugin({
            assetNameRegExp: /\.min\.css$/g,
            cssProcessor: require('cssnano'),
            cssProcessorPluginOptions: {
              preset: ['default', { discardComments: { removeAll: false } }],
            },
            canPrint: true
        })
    ],
    optimization: {
        minimizer: [new UglifyJsPlugin({
            include: /\.min\.js$/
        })]
    },
    devServer: {
        contentBase: __dirname + '/dist/js',
        port: 7700,
        watchContentBase: true
    } 
}]
```

Comment: loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader же, минифицирует ваш код. Закомментируйте объект и попробуйте скомпилировать

Comment: Это плагин для вывода скомпилированного кода в отдельный файл, если я его уберу, то я не получу в итоге ничего. Какую альтернативу вы можете посоветовать?

Comment: Дело в плагине который я указал выше. Я не вижу структуру полную, это отрывок из общей картины. В данном коде нет параметра отвечающего за минимизацию кода. Покажите полностью код вебпака. В особенности MiniCssExtractPlugin, как его инициализируете, возможно там стоит параметр на минимизацию. Но повторюсь, среди данных модулей нет того что вам необходимо.

Comment: Дополнил вопрос

Comment: У миникссплагина есть конфиг, посмотрите в документации

Comment: https://webpack.js.org/plugins/mini-css-extract-plugin/ в середине текста